# How to change Datetime field with queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime, field, django-queryset

this is the class

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    .
    .
    last_seen = models.DateTimeField(auto_add = True)
```

I want to change last_seen time with another time in the future

```
last_seen = Post.objects.get(author = user).last_seen
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    last_seen = timezone.now()
```

when I run print(last_seen) I find it does not change and still an old datetime value
what's the wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not saved the object post update. Hence it is not reflected. You can do the same by

```
your_post = Post.objects.get(author = user)
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    your_post.last_seen = timezone.now()
    your_post.update() // can also you object.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not update this for the post, you only set a *local variable* to the current timestamp.

You can update the `Post` record(s) for the authenticated user with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

if request.user.is_authenticated:
    Post.objects.filter(author=user).update(last_seen=now())
```